# How to replace case insentive string in python, with the target string in?

Tags: python, regex, string, case-insensitive

I know how to replace string in python, but I just want to add some mark around the target string while the target string is caseinsentive. Is there any simple way I can use?
For example, I want to add bracket around some words like:

```
"I have apple."  ->  "I have (apple)."
"I have Apple."  ->  "I have (Apple)."
"I have APPLE."  ->  "I have (APPLE)."
```

Comment: See `IGNORECASE` flag. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the matching case-insensitive.
You can include the flag in the pattern, as in:

```
import re

variants = ["I have apple.", "I have Apple.", "I have APPLE and aPpLe."]

def replace_apple_insensitive(s):
    # Adding (?i) makes the matching case-insensitive
    return re.sub(r'(?i)(apple)', r'(\1)', s)

for s in variants:
    print(s, '-->', replace_apple_insensitive(s))

# I have apple. --> I have (apple).
# I have Apple. --> I have (Apple).
# I have APPLE and aPpLe. --> I have (APPLE) and (aPpLe).
```

Or you can compile the regex and keep the case-insensitive flag out of the pattern:

```
apple_regex = re.compile(r'(apple)', flags=re.IGNORECASE) # or re.I
print(apple_regex.sub(r'(\1)', variants[2]))

#I have (APPLE) and (aPpLe).
```